# How to inherit variables to class

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having this:

```
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_database = 'publications';
```

saved as `connection.php` but i cant inerhit it's variables in this one:

```
namespace form;
include_once "Form.php";
include_once "connection.php";
class login extends Form
{
    public  function showLoginfrom()
    {
    echo '<form name="loginform"  method="get">';
    $login = new Form();
    $login->AddText('username','Your username');
    $login->AddPassword('password','','Your password');
    $login->SubmitButton('Login');
    echo "</form>";
}

public function executeLogin()
{
    $connection = new \mysqli($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password,$db_database);

    $username = ($_GET["username"]);
    $password = ($_GET["password"]);

    $query ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= '$username' AND password= '$password'";
    $result = $connection->query($query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)== 1)
    {
        echo "Welcome";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Login failed";
    }
}
```

I know that my code is unsafe, i am just experimenting. Its my first php program.

Comment: Please please please fix your SQL injection attack vulnerability: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Either use `global` (ew!), or inject them.

Comment: Take a look to http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You can create singleton for your connection, and use static method to get it. Just for learning

Comment: I generally make them constants instead of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Inject them into the method

For example;

```
public function executeLogin($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password,$db_database)
{
    $connection = new \mysqli($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password,$db_database);
```

And then call the `executeLogin()` method with those variables in the current scope.

#### Make properties

Two ways you can inject them to make properties. The first is exactly the same as above put in the `__construct()` method.

Another way is to include the files in the `__construct()` method and set them as properties. For example

```
private $arrDbDetails = array();

public function __construct() {
  include_once "connection.php";
  $this->arrDbDetails = array(
     'host' => $db_hostname,
     'user' => $db_username,
     'pass' => $db_password,
     'db'   => $db_database
  );
```

You can then access them with `$this->arrDbDetails['host']`, for example, in your `executeLogin()` method.

```
$connection = new \mysqli($this->arrDbDetails['host'],$this->arrDbDetails['user'],$this->arrDbDetails['pass'],$this->arrDbDetails['db']);
```

#### Using constants

You can also [`define`](http://php.net/define) the values and have them in the global scope.

```
define('DB_USERNAME', 'my_mysql_user');
```

And then call them as regular constants in your method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation:)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is using a class w/ static members. Something like:

```
class Config {
    static public $mysqli;
    static public $dbCredentials = [];
}
include('connection.php');
Config::$dbCredentials['host'] = $db_hostname;
// and repeat for the others
//optional, extra step:
Config::$mysqli = new \mysqli(...);
```

Then to use, you can do:

```
public function executeLogin()
{
    $connection = new \mysqli(\Config::$dbCredentials['host'], ..);
    //or
    $connection = \Config::$mysqli;
    // do other stuff
}
```

Other notes/alternatives:

- putting the `config` class in `connection.php` and doing that setup
  from there.
- using a getter function (ie `public static
  getConnection()`) to get the mysqli connection (probably use a singleton)
- using getter/setter functions for the credentials (ie `public static getDbHost()`)
- Use a proper Object Oriented approach and have `executeLogin` receive a `mysqli` object, which would be passed from the calling code.